# Could not find default Chrome binary

Tags: c#, asp.net, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the chrome webdriver for a project which works well when I run it on my local pc, however when I uploaded the project to my remote server for it to run live, the chromedriver could not load:

this is how I am calling my chromedriver:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\User\Downloads\chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0");
```

this is the error I get:

> Could not find default Chrome binary

I have made sure that:

1. the chromedriver.exe actually is in the specified location on the server
2. I upload the dlls needed for it to run

Any ideas please as to why this is happening?

Comment: I am encountering the same issue. Can help if this is resolved ?

Answer (score 4):

The WebDriver part is fine, but I found that the problem is that the code can't find Chrome.exe itself.

It should be installed in this folder:
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Please check this on Requirements: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

P.s: I tested myself and it works now. :)

Comment: hi again, did exactly this but still it says that file does not exist ... see http://betlikepros.com/simRequest.aspx