# Unable to resolve An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

## ***An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll***

I'm amid of learning a selenium C# tutorial and in the beginning stage. When I ran my Visual Studio console application I encountered the following error even after following [AnsweredLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074831/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-invalidoperationexception-occurred-in-we) !

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll Additional information: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174

### ***Consolie Application message***:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9) on port 56328 Only local connections are allowed.

***My Google Chrome browser version***

> Version 49.0.2623.75 (64-bit)

#### *My Sample C# Code Snippet:*

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Seleniumsecond
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var DRIVER_PATH = @"C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio   2013\Projects\Seleniumsecond\Seleniumsecond\bin\Debug\2.27\";
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(DRIVER_PATH);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com.sg");
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
            element.SendKeys("Execute Automation");
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

***How to resolve this exception ?***

Comment: This may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417903/could-not-find-default-chrome-binary

Comment: @Rob I tried the info mentioned in the thread. still same error. Please help

Comment: try something easier first as a path, put the driver in C:\drivers and be sure that it is not working in this case too, it might be a path issue

Comment: I tried the info mentioned in till same error. Please help. Is it due to Chrome Version ? my browser is Version 49.0.2623.75 (64-bit)

Comment: try changing visual studio build version, try "any cpu" and "X64"

Comment: also try installing a 32 bit chrome instead of the 64 version u r using.

Comment: I have already tried to change the build settings still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded my chrome version to Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit) in order to resolve the exception faced earlier

***My Google Chrome browser version***

> Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)

***My C# code snippet given below:***

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SeleniumThree
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.facebook.com");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            IWebElement Username = driver.FindElement(By.Name("FORMLOGINid"));
            Username.SendKeys("UserName");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            IWebElement Password = driver.FindElement(By.Name("FORMLOGINpwd"));
            Password.SendKeys("Password");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            IWebElement LoginButton = driver.FindElement(By.Name("btSubmit"));
            LoginButton.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            try
            {
                IWebElement MenuArrow = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//*[@id='id_arrow_popup_menu']/img"));
                MenuArrow.Click();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

            }

             catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            }

       }

   }
}
```

> Exception still faced in chrome Version 49.0.2623.75 (64-bit). It would be helpful is there is a Solution for lower version of chrome browser. Thanks